# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' sub-package or outside package

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

When I try to put a class / Activity in a sub-package or outside the main application package, it cannot find "R".
Having to manually import "R".

[Here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceIoR.png)

I understand that the manifest tells you in which package the "R" file has to be scoped.

[Here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NTnC.png)

How can I tell you from the gradle or from the manifest that I am using multiple packages without importing "R"?

Comment: What's wrong with importing `R`? Just like any other class, if you want to use it in a package that it's not in, you'll have to use an import or use the fully-qualified name. Also, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I just don't want it that way (for other architectural reasons). Would there be any way? as when you define multiple folders for the layouts that you modify the manifest with sourceSets.

Comment: No, if you want to use a class that's not in your package, then you have to import it. You might be able to hack the generation of `R` to produce it in multiple packages (or copy it after generation), but that's fickle and almost certainly not worth the hassle you get. Since you seem to be reluctant to explain your "architectural reasons", I can't even suggest a better alternative.

Comment: Sorry, the first sentence isn't quite corret: you can always reference the class by its fully qualified class name, then you don't have to import. But that's probably even worse than adding an import.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.